# Can I use Live Server inside Vscode editor?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, liveserver

I know live server opens with a browser.
But is it possible to open it inside editor?
Like I split the editor window with two .js files.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yup, you Open the pallet (Ctrl + Shift + P)

Select "Simple Browser: Preview" and then enter the web address

Answer (score 2):

you Open the pallet (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>)

Select *"Simple Browser: Show"* and then enter the web address

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should install a plugin named live preview instead of live server. click right in an html file. and then you can achive the live preview in vscode editor.

Here are two demo images. Hope my answer is helpful to you.

[demo image01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycF7h.png)
[demo image02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7V5Ku.png)